# Sitecore from Developer perspective

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I just started to look into Sitecore and I was wondering if anyone can help me enlighten what / how it is exactly from a developer perspective.

I've gone through bunch of their documentation and also their SDN - seems to me so far most of them are just drag/drop click here and there through their interface (ie. through their "Sitecore Desktop") with very minor actual programming.

Is this true? or are their actual C# / ASP.Net programming behind the scene to implement business logic and such?

I went through their basic tutorial (creating basic site for Product), and like I mentioned above, it's all mostly done through their interface without any real programming - as opposed to working with the ASP.Net MVC3 Music Store tutorial where you can see some C# programming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A Sitecore developer should have the most intense and deepest understanding of Sitecore in general. Developers need to understand the CMS user's perspective (i.e. content editor's POV), they need to understand the architecture of content within the content tree, and they need to know the code, which they build. A developer should have the most intimate knowledge of a Sitecore solution because you need to know the architecture to know how to code. And to know the architecture means you know how content editors will interact with the content.

### Architecture

Sitecore is a souped up database. Think of it like that. You can architecture a site how you want. But once you start to learn the principles of Sitecore architecture and best practices you'll notice a pattern. Everything in the content tree is an item. The model for each item (called a template in Sitecore terms) is defined by an architect (which is often often a developer). In fact, even if there's a separate person for the architect role, they likely have developer knowledge as architecture defines the way things are developed. In fact, the architecture is one of the most important things.

### Code

Code is broken down into various types, but in its simplest form there are two main things: **layouts** and **sublayouts**.

Think of a **layout** as what a normal a ASP.NET application uses a MasterPage for. In Sitecore, a layout is actually a ASPX WebForm, but it acts as a master page. Some examples of layouts you could have on your site are: One Column Layout, Two Column Layout, Print Layout. These would respectively translate to a header and footer with one main content area, a header and footer with a main column and side bar, and a print-optimized layout with maybe a logo and just main content.

**Sublayouts** are all of the little components that make up a page. Examples include: main navigation, a promo box in your side bar, a list of 5 recent news pieces, a CTA for a promotion, a sidebar slide show, etc. These components could be modular and moved around by content editors, *or* they can be fixed within the location of layouts, e.g. a promo box could always appear in the sidebar of the Two Column layout as a business rule defined in the code.

To answer your question about is there actual coding, yes. You write code using ASP.NET controls for Sitecore and Sitecore's C# API to access data that is populated into the templates on each item. So, if you had an item for a page that had a page title for the title tag, your code would use the Sitecore API to access the field "Title Tag" from the template (remember a template in Sitecore speak is a data model) in Sitecore.

### Coding For Sitecore

I'd say there are two approaches to coding. I believe you identified one of them, which is using the internal tools within Sitecore's interface. Sitecore has a section called Developer Center that lets you create layouts and sublayouts. Frankly, compare this to using Visual Studio in Design Mode all of the time. I have never once used the Developer Center to do my coding. Instead, I code in Visual Studio which is the most common technique for people to code for Sitecore (at least I think it is). Now if you're wondering, how does the coding connect to Sitecore's data... well the answer is within Sitecore. There's a section of the tree called Layouts. In here are the names of your layouts and sublayouts. Each layout and sublayout item has a path that maps to either a ASPX WebForm or ASCX User Control, respectively. This is how the code on the file system that you write in Visual Studio actually gets used by Sitecore. These layout and sublayout items are then used via the Presentation > Details tabs for each item in Sitecore.

### Beginners

One of the hardest things with Sitecore is the learning curve. I've been using Sitecore for years now and love it. In fact, its all I really do. It's by far my favorite CMS as its completely customizable and very developer-friendly. Sitecore recommends that new developers take the developer training classes so they can basically explain what I explained above in an actual training curriculum. In this training you will learn the architecture, and then how the code connects to it. Training involves hand-on architecture work within the content tree and hands-on coding. The recommend training courses for new developers are:

- [Getting Started With Sitecore Development: Sitecore XP 8 Website Development for .NET Developers (4 days, certification)](http://www.sitecore.net/services-and-support/training/back-end-developers/wnd8-sitecore-website-development-for-net-developers.aspx)
- [Further Training for Sitecore Certified Developers - Sitecore XP 8 Livefire MVC Workshop (1 day, no certification)](http://www.sitecore.net/services-and-support/training/back-end-developers/mvc-sitecore-livefire-mvc-workshop.aspx)

Comment: Great answer. I did the training and I can vouch for it. I'm confident that there are things that I just would not have understood quickly without it. Things like Standard Values and Insert Options.

Answer (score 6):

Sitecore is an ASP.NET application. That means that you can write any code you like. Our team creates all of the Sublayouts (ASCX files) and Layouts (ASPX files) ourselves in Visual Studio, not the editors built in to Sitecore.

Some installations of Sitecore that I have seen barely rely on the CMS to do the rendering. Instead values are pulled via the codebehind as if Sitecore was just a database. That can work fine in some situations.

The most impressive Sitecore instances use all of the available tools that the developer has access to. Using the Sitecore tools the way they were designed to be used allows some pretty impressive editing options for the (often non-technical) content editors.

For example: Using a Sitecore Fieldrenderer instead of just a placeholder or label will not only automatically render content appropriately (whether they are images or rich text), but it will **allow the content editor to edit the content right on the web page** as opposed to the only on back end that all CMS systems have.

**Workflow is another killer feature** for a customer that is the right size to afford Sitecore. It lets you build an approval process for items in the tree. That way legal, marketing and the graphics team call all sign off on a new page before it goes live. Then when all of the approvals are finalized, the site publishes automatically.

To sum up: Sitecore is a .NET application, you can code whatever you want. That means you should focus on the CMS features and make sure it is a good fit for you from a content editor perspective and a financial perspective.

Answer (score 4):

Sitecore is in most cases just drag & drop as you've described in terms of content authoring but to actually turn this content into a webpage you need to implement layouts, sublayouts and so on.

Layouts are generic ASP.NET pages (aspx), sublayouts are just web controls (ascx) and if you prefer you can also use XSLT to generate HTML but it's useful only for basics (Sitecore only supports XSLT 1 at this moment). These ASP.NET controls are more less the same as standard web forms controls with code behind and so on. The difference is that Sitecore is your datasource and it gives you an APIs to access all relevant applications.

But Sitecore APIs also goes beyond that and allows you programatic access to virtually any component of the framework. The APIs are well docummented and quite easy to understand and they can be used for more complex scenarios.

Latest version of Sitecore (6.4) allows you to also use MVC framework for layouts/sublayouts creation if you don't like web forms that much.

Answer (score 1):

Layouts and sublayouts are a great way todo any customizations from a coding standpoint but there is a third way that is not mentioned here. We call it sitecore extensions. I often find that to meet customer requirements, creating custom assembly's for workflow actions or template commands is the only way.
For example, a standard email notification upon entry into a workflow state only allows for you to apply server, recipient, description etc.. to action item field. In our case these values constantly change so we need to be more dynamic. A custom assembly applied to the action allows us the flexibility to do a number of things that the standard action will not. Another example was that we needed to have a treelist in an item scroll to and highlight the current item. The way todo this was to override the core treelist action with our custom assembly. 
Keep in mind that adding alot of code to the layout (which could be a master page for a ton of pages) ramps up the runtime overhead.

Answer (score 0):

From a UX perspective, Sitecore is impractical, overpowered and too complex to be effectively implemented for teams with typical content contributors and editors. No thought has been put into streamlining content creation or simple page template maintenance. I would never recommend Sitecore to a team without:

- HTML authoring/editing skills
- FTP concepts & Site tree understanding
- Data management skills

The system is built for developers, with users as a very distant after-thought. In my experience, it offers a huge number of benefits — being a usable system for every-day content authors is not one of those benefits. The system is so modular and over-managed, it forces users on every level to make decisions that only complicate otherwise simple operations. Content publishing is extremely modular, and a big benefit for developers; it is a catastrophe for everyday users.

If you're a developer, Sitecore is a wonderful building environment. It's powerful and flexible.

If you're a user, Sitecore is task-heavy and offers the steepest learning curve I've ever encountered with a CMS. UAT has been a nightmare.